# Fastest way of iterating and accessing elements of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, iteration

I am trying to implement a MATLAB code which is iterating and accessing elements using vectorization of array. Code snippet is below:

```
z=z(1:2:end)+j*z(2:2:end);
```

where "z" is an array containing I/Q stream value i.e alternating i & q like "iqiqiqiq...". I am trying to implement it using numpy array but with no success.

**Note:** Also looking for suggestions regarding any other way to implement the above logic which is even faster than copying MATLAB approach using numpy array and python-3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `z` is a numpy array of 64 bit floating points values, and the data in `z` is contiguous (e.g. you didn't form `z` by slicing it from a bigger array), you can create a complex *view* of `z` with *no copying*:

```
In [56]: z
Out[56]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

In [57]: z.view(np.complex128)
Out[57]: array([ 0.+1.j,  2.+3.j,  4.+5.j,  6.+7.j,  8.+9.j])
```

For completeness, here is the more direct (and less efficient) translation of your Matlab code.  It produces a copy:

```
In [63]: z[::2] + z[1::2]*1j
Out[63]: array([ 0.+1.j,  2.+3.j,  4.+5.j,  6.+7.j,  8.+9.j])
```

A more verbose but more efficient method to create a copy is:

```
In [73]: w = np.empty(len(z)//2, dtype=np.complex128)

In [74]: w.real = z[::2]

In [75]: w.imag = z[1::2]

In [76]: w
Out[76]: array([ 0.+1.j,  2.+3.j,  4.+5.j,  6.+7.j,  8.+9.j])
```

(I used `len(z)//2` for the size of `w`.  This assumes `z` is a one-dimensional array.)